# Run a project from jetty in intellij with run time info outputted to a file

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following scenario:
I run my application in development mode and use jetty as the web server.Maven is used to build the application. Is it possible to output the run time log to a file instead of in the IntelliJ environment ?That is instead of viewing the information in the window with the red arrow pointing towards it I want to display it in a file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a *Logs* tab in *Jetty Server running configuration* where you can choose to save console output to a file.

[image]